# Badge icons on mod history page overlap, don't look good

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools

On the mod history page, if a moderator has the Talkative and/or Outspoken badges, they are displayed next to their display name. Clearly this was designed to work with Stack Overflow, which has tiny badge icons:

[image]

See how the badges on Programmers are cramped together? Those on random's name look like a molecule. And even when only a single badge is displayed, it goes over the divider/table border. This also happens on every site that has wide badge icons:

[image]

This doesn't look very good.

Comment: This is a clear sign that I need more badges.

Answer (score 6):

While I'm sure Jin has a fix for it, I'd like to request that those badges be removed from display in the mod tools. Their presence does not convey any *useful* information. The dashboard should show, at a glance, how active a moderator has been for the selected time period. As such, there should be no static information in there, as it is pointless.

I guess the original intent was to record that the particular moderator engages with the community in chat (Talkative) and has useful posts that get starred (Outspoken). However, merely displaying the badge is not really useful, because it doesn't show if they stopped visiting chat or if they've been posting lolcats that get starred by everyone.

I personally do not think this is a useful statistic to have, and would suggest removing it altogether, which might be simpler to implement than coming up with a fix for each site.

Comment: This sounds like it should be an entirely different request